# Getting Error using Oauth to connect to Apigee

Tags: oauth, salesforce, apigee

I am trying to connect to Apigee for Kafka services from my Salesforce instance.
I am getting the below error trying to get the auth token:

{"fault":{"faultstring":"XMLToJSON[Products-to-JSON]: Source AccessEntity.ChildNodes.Access-App-Info.App.Credentials.Credential.ApiProducts is not available","detail":{"errorcode":"steps.xml2json.SourceUnavailable"}}}

Using the same parameters I am able to get the token using Postman.
Is there some configuration I am missing? 
I have added the token url to my Remote Site Settings.

Appreciate your help.

Comment: I'm not sure of your configuration but it looks like Apigee is trying to convert non-xml into json. Are you expecting XML back or JSON?

Answer (score 0):

If you're not trying to force the response to XML, check the two requests to make sure your Accept headers match... I'm guessing in the failed request you're sedning

```
Accept: text/xml
```

and for the working request you're sending

```
Accept: application/json
```